# Linking an SKScene to a UIViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, skscene

When you create a new game file in swift, by default you are given a GameScene.swift file, a GameViewController.swift file, and a UIViewController on your main.storyboard. In my code I have created another SKScene (similar to the GameScene already present), and I am having trouble linking it to another UIViewController that I have on my main.storyboard. I want to do this because i need to segue from my GameScene to this new scene and then to my Main ViewController / Initial Viewcontroller

How do I link the SKScene and ViewController correctly?

Below is the EndSceneViewController.swift file, and then the EndScene.swift file i want to link it to.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class EndSceneVC: UIViewController{


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        if let scene = EndScene(fileNamed:"EndScene") {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            scene.viewController = self
            skView.presentScene(scene)

        }
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return .AllButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .All
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}



import SpriteKit

class EndScene : SKScene {
    var viewController : UIViewController?

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        print("hello")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to move from scene to scene by switching controllers?

Root ViewController can be targeted from the currently displayed SKScene - you don't have to add another property to your scene.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        let viewController = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
    }
}
```